# Get Model back in Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to get information from my model during a result flagged HttpPost if I cannot pass it as a parameter?

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public FileUploadJsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, IwantMyModelToo! )
```

I can't really get the actual view model to go through the method, though. Any thoughts?

Here is the primary view. (FoldersController)

```
    <hr class="space" />
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderAction<Controllers.ImagesController>(i => i.Create(Model)); %>
    </div>
    <hr class="space" />
```

Here is the partial view (ImagesController, where the Create method resides)

```
// bunch of fun jQuery for jQuery Form Uploading.
</script>
<div class="span-24 last">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Image</legend>
        <form id="ajaxUploadForm" action="<%= Url.Action("Upload", "Images")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div>
            <label for="file">Select Image</label><br />
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
            <input id="ajaxUploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Please an you put in a snippet of the view that posts to your `Upload` action?

Comment: Done. The reason I am having trouble passing the value I want is because the jQuery form uploading process seems to stifle it.

Comment: There's nothing in here for the model to bind to.

Comment: What would I need to do to faciliate that? The model is passed from the FoldersController in the RenderAction method.

Comment: But you're posting from the form. Only the form data gets sent to the server - nothing else. Please see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code sample there are no properties connected to any model... Here I have added one (Foo) in a hidden form field, and created a class called MyModel.

**View**

```
<div class="span-24 last">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload Image</legend>
    <form id="ajaxUploadForm" action="<%= Url.Action("Upload", "Images")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div>
        <%= Html.Hidden("Foo", "bar") %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="file">Select Image</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
      </div>
      <input id="ajaxUploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Foo {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public FileUploadJsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, MyModel model)
{
  //model.Foo should be accessible here
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused. At what point do you pass the information through to the Controller? Where do you define the MyModel class? How does the controller know that the MyModel parameter matches the Hidden Field?

Comment: All the information that is to be sent to the server in the form post must be inside the form tags. The property `Foo` is inferred by ASP.NET MVC, but you could do `MyModel.Foo` or something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to work. I really don't see where you're getting anything from. Where do you create a new instance of the myModel class? Why does it magically accept a myModel object in the parameter list? I just don't see where any of it adds up. I'm sitting here trying it on my end and all I get is 'null'.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC creates an instance of `MyModel` and populates the values (in this case `Foo`) based on the posted form data that is sent to the server. There's not really a lot to say about this process as it's all handled automatically by the default model binder.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it... so ASP.NET MVC will automatically inject any objects passed from the view into the controller - and if you parametrize something with its type, it'll assign it there?

Comment: Thank you, I think this is starting to make sense. The work done by the model binder behind the scenes is what was confusing me.

Comment: Well, they're not really objects. In this case, they're hidden form values. When you post the form, ASP.NET MVC will see that one of those form keys is `Foo` and will then look at what parameters are being used in action, and will then go about instantiating them with the values from the form data.